# When to use definitive article with "internet"?

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire

I saw an edit to a question someone else had asked a long time ago, in which the OP had originally written "J'utilise l'internet" (which is exactly what I might have written) and it was corrected to "J'utilise internet."

When asked how I have learned what little I know of French, I have always answered that "je l'ai appris sur l'internet (et par des livres)," which I believed to be a correct way of saying "I learned it online and from books."

Is this not correct? I would swear I've seen "l'internet" many times. Does it not take a definitive article?

Comment: Oh, thanks @Stephane. Side note, is "apprendre par des livres" a correct translation of "learn from books" ?

Comment: “En lisant des livres” sounds better.

Comment: Usuellement, on apprend *dans* les livres. Michel Jeury dans "Nounou" : "Alors, c'est mal, d'apprendre dans les livres ?"... et bien d'autres.